# Php output for categories

Tags: php, ajax, categories

I have a shop with more than 30k categories in it and it's almost impossible to edit products in admin because the way it handles categories selection in products edit page it's not designed for that amount of categories. It loads very long and sometimes even crashes. It's a simple select box and I wonder what can be done?

Do I need ajax for this to work?

Here's the code:

```
<?php function custom_catalog_tree($category_id=0, $depth=1, $count=0) {

$output = '';

if ($category_id == 0) {
$output .= '<div class="checkbox" id="category-id-'. $category_id .'"><label>'. functions::form_draw_checkbox('categories[]', '0', (isset($_POST['categories']) && in_array('0', $_POST['categories'], true)) ? '0' : false, 'data-name="'. htmlspecialchars(language::translate('title_root', 'Root')) .'" data-priority="0"') .' '. functions::draw_fonticon('fa-folder', 'title="'. language::translate('title_root', 'Root') .'" style="color: #cccc66;"') .' ['. language::translate('title_root', 'Root') .']</label></div>' . PHP_EOL;
}

// Output categories
$categories_query = database::query(
  "select c.id, ci.name
  from ". DB_TABLE_CATEGORIES ." c
  left join ". DB_TABLE_CATEGORIES_INFO ." ci on (ci.category_id = c.id and ci.language_code = '". language::$selected['code'] ."')
  where c.parent_id = '". (int)$category_id ."'
  order by c.priority asc, ci.name asc;"
);

while ($category = database::fetch($categories_query)) {
  $count++;

  $output .= '  <div class="checkbox"><label>'. functions::form_draw_checkbox('categories[]', $category['id'], true, 'data-name="'. htmlspecialchars($category['name']) .'" data-priority="'. $count .'"') .' '. functions::draw_fonticon('fa-folder fa-lg', 'style="color: #cccc66; margin-left: '. ($depth*1) .'em;"') .' '. $category['name'] .'</label></div>' . PHP_EOL;

  if (database::num_rows(database::query("select * from ". DB_TABLE_CATEGORIES ." where parent_id = '". $category['id'] ."' limit 1;")) > 0) {
    $output .= custom_catalog_tree($category['id'], $depth+1, $count);
  }
}

database::free($categories_query);

return $output;
}

echo custom_catalog_tree();
?>
```

Comment: Do you really need to display 30k options in a select box?

Comment: It's for admin backend. I have this amount of categories and yes I need to various categories to be attached to the product.

Comment: A shop with more than 30k categories...? Think you should redesign your shop / categories either than trying to displaying them all faster. No human brain can handle 30k categories, not worth at all. Really talking about categories, or are we more talking about something like tags?

Comment: Probably not even the browser can handle 30k options in a select box.. Well, depends on the computer ressources, but I guess it's a bad solution..

Comment: I don't think displaying 30k categories is a good idea, maybe a redesign of the system is in order. If you did do it though, I bet there would be a way to only load categories on demand. For example, load the first twenty categories, if the user scrolls down more THEN load another 20.

Comment: I'm asking for advice from code point of view and not how to run my shop. It's a shop for car parts, so every category represents car model. I.E. Toyota > Camry > 3.0 V6. So this is why the category amount is that high. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah but are you loading ALL of that in a select box?

Comment: Yes, that's how it's made by default. It was ok maybe till 1000 categories, but after that it began to slow down. Most of the time I dont attach categories by hand as I import products from CSV, but when I do need to edit other product info it's impossible to work .

Comment: You seriously need to redesign the system, don't hit a select box with so much data at once. Load the data on demand only. For example you could have one select box that is dedicated to manufacturers, fill that first, then use the manufacturer value selected in a SQL query as a filter for the next thing to find. For example you could have a select drop down for Manufacturer, a select drop down for model, a select drop down for cylinders etc.. That way you narrow the search down and don't flood a single select box.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make a search box instead of a select box. Write down a query to search the product category with ajax if you can. Make a search query with select * from table_name where category like %your_value%

Comment: I've managed ajax search instead select box, but I can't get it to show which categories are checked after page refresh. Here's a fraction my code: <label>'+
     '<input type="checkbox" class="result checkbox pull-left" value="'+ result.id +'" name="categories[]"' +
                    '    <div class="title">'+ result.title +'</div>' +
                    '    <div class="description"><small>'+ result.description +'</small></div>' +
                    '</input>' +
     '</label>'

Answer (score 0):

You can easily handle this using [Select2](https://select2.github.io) plugin. 
It provides a suggestion dropdown, where users can type and filter through dropdown values.

On server side you have to create web service to fetch categories by name.

Go through section **Loading remote data**,

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax